# Make a html template centralized

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

In all the form I have below code in blade.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Price</label>
        <input name="Price" type="number" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

I know, by using **[laravelcollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html)** the input type text above can be handled like below..

```
Form::number('Price', '');
```

Is there any way to make it centralized to avoid writing this again and again for each field such that there will be no need to write this whole template (6 lines above html part) every time for each database field?

Answer (score 0):

Why not go like this:

Step 1: Create a folder called `partials`

Step 2: Create `_form_field.blade.php` in partials folder

Step 3: Copy and paste it the below code in the newly created file

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">{{ $labelName }}</label>
        <input name="{{ $input['name'] }}" type="{{ $input['type'] }}" class="{{ $input['class'] }}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use this file and include it anywhere you want in your views. Like so:

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('your_main_layout_file_here')

@section('content')

    <form action="{{ route('yourPostRoute') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        @include('partials._form_field', [
            'labelName' => 'Price',
            'input'     => [
                'type'  => 'number',
                'name'  => 'Price',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ]
        ])
    </form>

@endsection
```

Hope this helps you out.